# OpenGL vs OpenGL ES (GLchar and more)

Tags: android, ios, opengl, opengl-es

I just caught a little quirk in my fledgling application's GL interfaces. On desktop GL things like glShaderSource() take a GLchar*, but on the mobile GLES interfaces they take a plain char*.

Now, this is really a very trivial thing to fix. Since GLchar is a typedef of char anyway, one can just use char* on desktop GL and be alright everywhere.

However, seeing this issue raises concerns in me about coming across other compatibility issues in the GL vs GLES realm. Of course I know that GLES 2.0 is basically a stripped down OpenGL 2.0, and that I'll have to suffer the loss of things like the fixed function pipeline. But will it get any worse that that? I was hoping that the interfaces which GLES 2.0 did leave for me would at least work identically to their desktop GL counterparts. But is this indeed the case? I sure do hope so.

Answer (score 1):

> But is this indeed the case?

No.

For example, glTexSubImage2D doesn't work in ES 2.0 like it does in desktop GL. The internal format and pixel format parameters take entirely different values, values that would not be legal in most cases with desktop GL.

You should not expect ES 2.0 code to run without changes on desktop GL.

Comment: I just had a look at both the desktop GL and mobile GLES docs for glTexSubImage2D, and I think you missed a subtle point in my question. It seems that on both platforms glTexSubImage2D does actually have common forms, like GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4 exists everywhere for example. It's just that I hope that if I use the same functions, with all the same constants, that they will then have  the same semantics on GL and GLES. What I'm worried about is functions that might look totally compatible API wise, but might work differently internally in some really *non-obvious* way.